# Default Nagivatinal Drawer Layout of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am trying to figure out how to call the navigation layout of android studio to all the activities.

The Navigation Bar works absolutely fine with first activity. I am not sure how to call the same navigation layout to the second activity.

Code of my Second activity:

```
public class Screen2 extends Activity {

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use fragments it's not activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this is the layout of you `MainActivity`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now you want same navigation drawer to other activity i.e `Main2Activity` add this to other activity

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And if your first item of navigation drawer points to mainActivity then in `onCreate()` of main activity use this

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true); 
}
```

And in 2nd activity just call the same code with only difference in the item you want to be selected as

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);///Change 1 as per your choice of child
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am new to android, Could you please explain in brief

Comment: Check the asnwer , and if it helped dont forget to accept the answer and rate up.

Comment: Thanks for your time on answering my question. I am not choosing any item. Instead i Have a onclick listener with my first activity, Listening to the click it takes me to screen2. Where i have my nav layout missing. How do i get Nav Layout even to screen 2 is my Question

Comment: thats what is posted above , just copy paste the same navigation drawer xml layout to other activities xml, and it will appear there

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a parent class for all the activities which require the navigation drawer.
All the activities will extend this class and you will have the navigation drawer in all the activities.

You can then inflate the main content layout with custom views inside the oncreate methods of the activities.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use fragments than different activities with drawer.